# Bug using state_machines gem - state variable returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, state-machine

When I'm doing

```
d = Design.find_by(id: 1111, state: 'in_stock')
```

I getting a perfect result meaning that the database record has the value for state persisted / stored as in_stock.

but when I do

```
d.state => nil
```

I using [state_machines](https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines) gem to implement state machine

```
class Design < ActiveRecord::Base
 state_machine initial: :sold_out do

  event :stock_added do
   transition [:processing, :sold_out, :seller_out_of_stock, :blocked,
    :banned, :review, :on_hold, :reject] => :in_stock
  end

  event :stock_removed do
   transition [:blocked, :in_stock, :sold_out] => :seller_out_of_stock
  end

  before_transition to: :in_stock do |design|
   design.last_in_stock = Time.now
   if design.designer.vacation?
    design.designer_vacation
    false
   end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: have you tried  
    `d = Design.find '111`  
    `d.stock_added` or `d.stock_added!`  
    `d.reload`  
    `d.state`

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines/issues/16
https://github.com/state-machines/state_machines-activerecord